# evaluating a contour integral where c is $4x^2+y^2=2$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

Consider the integral
$$\oint_C \frac{\cot(\pi z)}{(z-i)^2} dz,$$  where $C$ is the contour of $4x^2+y^2=2$.

The answer seems to be $$2 \pi i\left(\frac{\pi}{\sinh^2 \pi} - \frac{1}{\pi}\right)$$ but I do not know how to proceed.
I would be grateful if an answer contains some worked out steps on how to proceed with this problem.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages learning, you will get much more help if you show us what you have already done. Could you edit your question with your thoughts and ideas?

Comment: Have you already learned the residue theorem?

Comment: sorry if my editing is bad , i am new to this website and have no 
clue how to include the symbols , 
yes i have learnt the residue theorem, i am reading on complex analysis after a gap of 6 years so not able to solve problems spontaneously

here is my thoughts 

pole z0= i of order 2 
by residue theorem and cauchy integral formula  2πin!fn(z0)=∮cf(z)(z−z0)n+1 
so 2πi 1! f'(z0)= 2πi*{ -πcosec^2(πi)} 
2πi*[-π/sin^2(πi)] , 
I am thinking the answer given may be wrong or my solution is wrong , am i right in assuming f(z)= cot(πz) analytic and differentiable on the contour ellipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints.**

(A) $\cot(\pi z)$ is a meromorphic function having residue equal to $\frac{1}{\pi}$ for every $z\in\mathbb{Z}$;

(B) $\frac{1}{(z-i)^2}$ is a meromorphic function with a double pole in $z=i$;

(C) If $\gamma$ is a simple closed curve in the complex plane and $f(z)$ is a meromorphic function with no singularities on $\gamma$, then:
$$\oint_{\gamma}f(z)\,dz = 2\pi i\cdot \sum_{\zeta\in Z}\operatorname{Res}\left(f(z),z=\zeta\right)$$
where $Z$ is the set of singularities of $f(z)$ inside $\gamma$.

---

Inside the given countour there are just two singularities for $f(z)=\frac{\cot(\pi z)}{(z-i)^2}$, in $z=0$ and $z=i$.
Since $\operatorname{Res}(f(z),z=0)=-\frac{1}{\pi}$, we just need to compute $\operatorname{Res}(f(z),z=i)$.

$z=i$ is a double pole for $f(z)$, hence:

$$\operatorname{Res}(f(z),z=i)=\lim_{z\to i}\frac{d}{dz}(z-i)^2 f(z)=-\lim_{z\to i}\frac{\pi}{\sin^2(\pi z)}=\frac{\pi}{\sinh^2 \pi}.$$